# MVC3 ActionLink With / without Image differences

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, jquery-ui-dialog

I went through the different posts and found an extension to create an Action Link Helper that will add an image as the link as follows.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string actioNName, string imgUrl, string alt, object routeValues, object linkHtmlAttributes, object imageHtmlAttributes)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var url = urlHelper.Action(actioNName, routeValues);

    //Create the link
    var linkTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
    linkTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url);
    linkTagBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(linkHtmlAttributes));

    //Create image
    var imageTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
    imageTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", urlHelper.Content(imgUrl));
    imageTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("alt", urlHelper.Content(alt));
    imageTagBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(imageHtmlAttributes));

    //Add image to link
    linkTagBuilder.InnerHtml = imageTagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

    //return linkTagBuilder.ToString();
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(linkTagBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Which produces the proper HTML that I "think I need" But I get an error when I run it, 'Object Doesnt Support this property or method'. However when I just use the MVC HtmlAction Link that creates basically the same thing it does work. I think the problem is the fact that its nested, and I would have to change the jQuery code to launch the dialog. Here is the code for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $("<div></div>")
                    .addClass("dialog")
                    .attr("id", $(this).attr("data-dialog-id"))
                    .appendTo("body")
                    .dialog({
                        title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                        close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                        modal: true
                    })
                    .load(this.href);
        });

        $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the HTML that gets produces with the image and without, one works one doesnt.

```
//Without the Image and it works fine
      <a class="openDialog" data-dialog-id="emailDialog" data-dialog-title="Contact Us" href="/Home/ContactUs">Contact Us</a>

//With the Image that produces an Error
                <a class="openDialog" data_dialog_id="emailDialog" data_dialog_title="Contact Us" href="/Home/ContactUs"><img alt="Contact us" src="Content/images/common_en/subnavi_contact.png" /></a>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your error? In jquery or the helper? Did you debug?

Comment: The error actually happens on jQuery call. in the javascript on the line -- .AppendTo("body") generates the "Does not support this method or Property" I did debug both with the version that worked and the one that doesnt and cant seem to find the differences between calls.

Comment: can you show the whole error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, make sure the error is happening on the appendTo line:

```
var newDiv = $("<div></div>");
newDiv.addClass("dialog");
newDiv.attr("id", $(this).data("dialog-id"));
newDiv.appendTo($('body')); // is error really here?
newDiv.dialog({
    title: $(this).data("dialog-title"),
    close: function () { $(this).remove() },
    modal: true
}).load(this.href);
```

Also, what version of jQuery are you using? You can use the data() function instead of the attr() function to shorthand the code a bit.

**Update after comment**

My bad! I didn't realize: when inside of dialog, $(this) no longer refers to the .openDialog link. Try this instead:

```
var newDiv = $("<div></div>");
newDiv.addClass("dialog");
newDiv.attr("id", $(this).data("dialog-id"));
newDiv.appendTo($('body')); // is error really here?
var anchor = $(this);
newDiv.dialog({
    title: anchor.data("dialog-title"),
    close: function () { $(this).remove() },
    modal: true
}).load(this.href);
```

Comment: This version works just fine. One think I noticed though, the Title of the dialog no longer shows up with the Image version, however, the text-link version still shows the title. Getting there, thanks for the help. Any ideas on the title coming through?

Comment: I did try the updated version still didnt bring the title in on the dialog. Through the watch window it shows data as a function, and anchor.data("dialog-title") , returns undefined

Comment: Then your anchor needs to look like this: `<a class="openDialog" data-dialog-title="Title for the dialog" ...`

Comment: THANKS olive, through all my trials and changes of the helper, and the javascript, somehow the helper changed all the "-" to "_" so they couldnt get picked up. I changed the call from .data , to .attr and referenced the "data_dialog_title" and now the title displays in the dialog. Thanks for your help again.